# Как передать изображение в браузер через http python socket

Tags: python, изображения, сервер, http, сокет

Пишу простой сервер на python, используя библиотеку встроенную socket. Разобрался с отправкой html, css, но не могу отправить изображение. Везде во всех примерах, что я видел, делают просто 2 сокета для клиента и сервера и в них пускают бесконечный цикл, который качает картинку. Но мне это не подходит, ведь я хочу получить изображение на своей html-странице в браузере. Какое есть решение?

функция, которая достаёт изображение, читает и возвращает

```
def get_image():
    with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as img:
        return img.read()
```

Сам код сокета

```
import socket
from views import get_home_page, get_about_page, get_image
from static_route import get_static


URLS = {
    '/': get_home_page,
    '/about/': get_about_page,
    '/image.jpg': get_image # здесь я получаю ссылку на функцию, 
                            # которая вернёт мне мою картинку в виде байт-строки
}


def parse_request(request):
    parsed = request.decode('utf-8').split(' ')
    method, url = parsed[:2]
    return method, url


def generate_headers(method, url):
    if method != 'GET':
        return ('HTTP/1.1 405 Method not allowed\n\n', 405)
    
    if url not in URLS:
        return ('HTTP/1.1 404 Page not found\n\n', 404)
    
    return ('HTTP/1.1 200 Content-Type: text/html OK\n\n', 200)


def generate_content(code, url):
    if code == 404:
        return '<h1>404</h1><p>Page not found</p>'
    if code == 405:
        return '<h1>405</h1><p>Method not allowed</p>'
    return URLS[url]()


def generate_response(request):
    method, url = parse_request(request)
    if 'static' in url:
        return get_static(method=method, url=url).encode()
    
    # Здесь обрабатываю запрос картинки
    if 'image' in url:
        img_binary = URLS[url]()
        return b'HTTP/1.1 200 Content-Type: image/jpeg\n\n OK\n\n' + b'Content-Length: ' + str(len(img_binary)).encode() + img_binary
    
    headers, code = generate_headers(method, url)
    body = generate_content(code, url)

    return (headers + body).encode()


# AF_INET - IPv4 protocol, SOCK_STREAM - TCP protocol
def run():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9000))
    server_socket.listen()
    
    while True:
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
        request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        response = generate_response(request)

        client_socket.send(response)
        client_socket.close()


if __name__  == '__main__':
    run()
```

Вот ответ от браузера, вроде ошибок нет, если перейти по адресу http://127.0.0.1:9000/image.jpg, то скачается картинка, но открыть её не получается, или часть данных не передается или ещё что-то, не знаю, что делать.
[image: ответ браузера]

Comment: Поле `Content-Length:` должно быть в Response Headers, а у вас оно съехало в тело ответа

Comment: Упс, не обратил внимание, переделал на вот такое b'HTTP/1.1 200 Content-Type: image/jpeg OK Content-Length: ' + str(len(img_binary)).encode() + b'\n\n' + img_binary и всё заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, я неправильно написал headers, у меня Content-legth улетело в тело запроса, исправил и всё заработало

```
b'HTTP/1.1 200 Content-Type: image/jpeg OK Content-Length: ' + str(len(img_binary)).encode() + b'\n\n' + img_binary
```